# How to reset Nuxt app's states upon logout?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, pinia

When the user logs out of the app, the Pinia persistent `authStore` state is reset, and the user is redirected to /login. However, if the next user logs in without refreshing the page, the main page still displays the previous user's data, as it's still in the page's state. How could I fix this?

How could I reset every state in the app upon logout? What is the recommended solution to shield one auth session's states from another one?

I've tried manually resetting the page's state when the "logout" button *in the page* is pressed, just in case there's no refresh later, but this can only take me so far: much of the time, the button+its handler are located in a Layout, or an isolated page in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I've found is to trigger a full-blown reload of the app, calling [`reloadNuxtApp`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/reload-nuxt-app) after I logout. This does the trick.

Comment: There is a specific method for a full reset AFAIK. Reloading the whole page seems extreme to me.

Comment: Would love to see a separate answer about it. Yes, it's pretty extreme, that's why I'd consider this a workaround at most, not a legitimate solution.